# Why does (360 / 24) / 60 = 0 ... in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, division

I am trying to compute (360 / 24) / 60 I keep getting the answer 0.0 when I should get 0.25

In words: I want to divide 360 by 24 and then divide the result by 60

```
public class Divide {

    public static void main(String[] args){
      float div = ((360 / 24) / 60);
      System.out.println(div);

    }
}
```

This prints out:

> 0.0

Why is that? Am I doing something really stupid, or is there a good reason for this

Comment: I tried the same with GCC (C) and it suffers the same issue.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

None of the operands in the arithmetic is a float - so it's all being done with integer arithmetic and *then* converted to a float. If you change the type of an appropriate operand to a float, it'll work fine:

```
float div = ((360 / 24f) / 60); // div is now 0.25
```

Note that if you changed just 60 to be a float, you'd end up with the 360 / 24 being performed as integer arithmetic - which is fine in this particular case, but doesn't represent what I suspect you really intended. Basically you need to make sure that arithmetic operation is being performed in the way that you want.

Comment: More exact:
360/24 = 15
15/60 = 0

Rounded always to integers ;)

Comment: *sigh*. Monomorphic numeric literals confuse people. Polymorphic numeric literals confuse people. You just can't win.

Answer (score 24):

You're actually doing integer division ([JLS 15.17.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.17.2)).

```
float div = ((360 / 24) / 60);
float div = (float) ((360 / 24) / 60);
float div = (float) (15 / 60);
float div = (float) (0);
float div = 0F;
```

To do floating point division, at least one of the operands need to be a floating point numeric type.

```
float div = ((360F / 24) / 60);
float div = 15F / 60;
float div = 0.25F;
```

---

Tip: if precision is important, you want to do as much of the calculation with `double`, before converting to `float`. In fact, unless your profiling demonstrates that you absolutely need `float`, you should always prefer `double`.

```
    float f;

    f = (1E-17F * 1E-17F);
    System.out.println(f); // prints "9.999999E-35"

    f = (float) (1E-17D * 1E-17D);
    System.out.println(f); // prints "1.0E-34"
```

Comment: don't you mean `double` in "In fact, you should probably use `float` almost always"?

Answer (score 2):

In your main method,

```
public static void main(String[] args){
      float div = ((360 / 24) / 60);
      System.out.println(div);
}
```

Note that 360, 24 and 60 are all integer values. As such you will obtain weird values.

360/24 -> 15 (perfectly fine)
15 / 60 -> 0.4 (floating point)

Unfortunately for you floating point numbers are truncated thus you get:

```
-> 0 (integer value)
```

Then, by assigning 0 to a floating point variable, you change 0 to a floating point value, 0.0. Thus the result.

If you want to divide them you need to change them into floating point values.

The correct code should be as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
      float div = ((360.0 / 24.0) / 60.0);
      System.out.println(div);
}
```