# ArithmeticException Java?

Tags: java

Can anyone help me find where the execption is? I can't seem to find the problem..

```
  public void fieldChanged(Field f, int context){
        //if the submit button is clicked
     try{
      stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      timeTaken = stopTime - startTime;
      timeInSecs = ((timeTaken/1000));
      speed = 45/timeInSecs;
      Dialog.alert("Speed of Delivery: " + speed + "mph");
      }
     catch(ArithmeticException e){
      Dialog.alert("error " + speed);
      e.printStackTrace();

     }

    }
```

startTime variable is a global variable..

edit:
how can timeinSecs = 0? I cant seem to get my debugger working for the BlackBerry JDE so someone will have to help me out :( timeTaken should be the time in ms from pushing the point of pushing a start button to the pont of pushing the stop button...

all other variables are global as well

Comment: What exception are you getting?  Where are the other variables (stopTime, timeTaken, timeInSecs) defined?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Exceptions have types, and what this allows is for you to look up the type and quickly categorize the problem. From the documentation:

> [`ArithmeticException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html):
>   Thrown when an exceptional arithmetic condition has occurred. For example, an integer "divide by zero" throws an instance of this class.

Moreover, most exceptions are constructed with a message to help you even further figure out what happened.

```
try {
    int i = 0 / 0;
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This prints:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at [filename:line number]
```

***But how did this happen?***

Java, like many other programming languages, distinguishes between integer division and floating point division.

#### [JLS 15.17.2 Division Operator /](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.17.2)

> The binary `/` operator performs division, producing the quotient of its operands. The left-hand operand is the dividend and the right-hand operand is the divisor. Integer division rounds toward 0. [...] if the value of the divisor in an integer division is 0, then an `ArithmeticException` is thrown.

The following may surprise you if you're not familiar with integer division:

```
    System.out.println(1/2); // prints "0"
```

What happens here is that since both the dividend and the divisor are `int`, the operation is an integer division, whose result is rounded to an `int`. Remember that an `int` can only contain whole number (of limited range, some 4 billion numbers approximately).

You can specify that you need a floating point division by making at least one of the operands a floating point number.

```
    System.out.println(1/2.0); // prints "0.5"
    System.out.println(1D/2); // prints "0.5"
```

`D` is a special suffix for numeric literal to specify that it's a `double`-precision value. There's also `L` for `long` (64-bit integer).

A `double` value needs to be stored in a `double` variable.

```
    double v = 1D / 2; // v == 0.5
    int i = 1D / 2; // DOESN'T COMPILE!!! Explicit cast needed!
```

Note that which division is performed doesn't have anything to do with what type it'll eventually go to. It only depends on what type the dividend and divisor are.

```
    double v = 1 / 2; // v == 0.0 (!!!)
```

You should also note that `double` too, is a limited precision number.

```
    System.out.println(.2D + .7D - .9D); // prints "-1.1102230246251565E-16"
```

***But what about my code?***

So now, let's focus on what happened with your code:

```
  timeTaken = stopTime - startTime;
  timeInSecs = ((timeTaken/1000));
  speed = 45/timeInSecs;
```

More than likely what happened is that `timeTaken` is declared as a `long`. Therefore `timeTaken/1000` results in integer division. If `timeTaken < 1000`, the result of the division is `0`.

At this point, it doesn't matter if `timeInSecs` is a `double` or a `float`, because the integer division has already been performed. This means that `timeInSecs` would be either `0` or `0.0`, depending on its type.

From the error you get, though, one can determine that `timeInSecs` is likely to be an integer type. Otherwise, `45/timeInSecs` would result in a floating point division that results in `Infinity` (a special `double` value) instead of throwing `ArithmeticException`.

***So how do we fix this?***

We can fix this by declaring the variables as follows:

```
long timeTaken;
double timeInSecs;
double speed;
```

And then performing the calculation as follows (note that `1000` is now a `double` value).

```
timeTaken = stopTime - startTime;
timeInSecs = timeTaken/1000D;
speed = 45D/timeInSecs; // D is not necessary here, but it's good for clarity
```

#### See also

- [Why does (360 / 24) / 60 = 0 … in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475652/why-does-360-24-60-0-in-java)
- [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Probably right here: `speed = 45/timeInSecs;`

Make sure that timeInSecs is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

Make `timeInSecs` and `speed` floats, and do:

```
timeInSecs = (timeTaken/1000.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

45 / 0 time taken reaches zero and you have division by zero at

speed = 45/timeInSecs;

Answer (score 0):

`timeInSecs` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a division by zero in line 6 of the method body.

Answer (score 0):

You can't divide with zero, need extra error handling on every divide part.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is probably something wrong with startime calculation and it is actually equal to stoptime. Other thing could be the difference is actually going beyond the limit of the integer, probably use a long.