# division problems

Tags: java, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does (360 / 24) / 60 = 0 … in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475652/why-does-360-24-60-0-in-java)

This line of code:

```
System.out.println ("array[j], "+array[j]+", divided by sum, "+sum+", equals: array[j]/sum: "+ array[j]/sum) ;
```

is yeilding this line of text:

> array[j], 21, divided by sum, 100, equals: array[j]/sum: 0

why is it doing this? (everything is right eccept that the answer should be .21)

Comment: right the problem was that its integers and i need doubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that your array is not **integer** ?

if it's, try using double.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that `aray` is an `int[]` and `sum` is an `int`. In this case, Java will perform integer division, which results in 0 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Others noted the cause. To fix, `(double) aray[j]/sum`.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing integers will get you an integer answer rounded down to the first whole number. If you want a decimal result, you have to make it 21.0/100.0.