# Why am I getting different results for this but really they are the same numbers?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does (360 / 24) / 60 = 0 … in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475652/why-does-360-24-60-0-in-java)

float answer = 5/2; and float answer 5.0/2.0;

When I add the decimal point I get 2.5 which is correct but without the decimal I get 2??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553047/wrong-division-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475652/why-does-360-24-60-0-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017058/division-problems ... there are probably a million more

Answer (score 4):

Integer division is different from floating point division.  In your first example, you are dividing two integers, getting the result 2, and then assigning it to a float.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple. 5/2 is evaluated according to integer division (since 5 and 2 are integers), the result is 2 (integer division gives the quotient, i.e. the division rounded down) and this is converted to a float. 5.0/2.0 does a floating-point division, so you get the correct answer of 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because when you are using 5 and 2, the numbers are being interpreted as integers, which also results in a rounded integer, which then casts to the float "answer".  When you specify 5.0 and 2.0, these are considered floats, which allows the results to also be a float.

Answer (score 1):

From the Java Documentation for numeric promotion : http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#239829

> 15.17.2 Division Operator /
>
> The binary / operator performs division, producing the quotient of its
>   operands. The left-hand operand is the dividend and the right-hand
>   operand is the divisor. **Integer division rounds toward 0. That is, the
>   quotient produced for operands n and d that are integers after binary
>   numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is an integer value q whose magnitude is as
>   large as possible while satisfying |d·q||n|; moreover, q is positive
>   when |n||d| and n and d have the same sign, but q is negative when
>   |n||d| and n and d have opposite signs.** There is one special case that
>   does not satisfy this rule: if the dividend is the negative integer of
>   largest possible magnitude for its type, and the divisor is -1, then
>   integer overflow occurs and the result is equal to the dividend.
>   Despite the overflow, no exception is thrown in this case. On the
>   other hand, if the value of the divisor in an integer division is 0,
>   then an ArithmeticException is thrown.

The result of 5/2 is an integer, your then casting that integer to a float during assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first one is based on integers.  The division gets rounded to 2 because of it.  Then it gets casted into float.

The second one is based on floats right from the start, so you get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

you calculate in integers and use therefore integer arithmetics. The cast to float happens after the calculation. you could write

float answer = ((float) 5) / ((float) 2)