# regex to split a string in half in java

Tags: java, regex

we need help how to write the regex for string.split so we can split a string in half.

thanks.

Comment: this is not a problem for regex. You can compute the length of the string, just split on length/2.

Comment: Please make your question clearer with an example.

Comment: @Bart: nice one, I should've thought of it. Though I think it's GOOD that I didn't think of it. I enjoy toying with regex, but I wouldn't want it to be my first instinct.

Comment: @polygenelubricants, to be honest, I had expected you to put something like that in your original post as a tongue-in-cheek solution :)

Answer (score 21):

There's no *obvious* regex pattern that would do this. It *may* be possible to do this with `String.split`, but I'd just use `substring` like this:

```
    String s = "12345678abcdefgh";

    final int mid = s.length() / 2;
    String[] parts = {
        s.substring(0, mid),
        s.substring(mid),
    };

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts)); 
    // "[12345678, abcdefgh]"
```

The above would split an odd-length `String` with `part[1]` one character longer than `part[0]`. If you need it the other way around, then simply define `mid = (s.length() + 1) / 2;`

---

#### *N*-part `split`

You can also do something like this to split a string into *N*-parts:

```
static String[] splitN(String s, final int N) {
    final int base = s.length() / N;
    final int remainder = s.length() % N;

    String[] parts = new String[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int length = base + (i < remainder ? 1 : 0);
        parts[i] = s.substring(0, length);
        s = s.substring(length);
    }
    return parts;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
    String s = "123456789";

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitN(s, 2)));  
    // "[12345, 6789]"

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitN(s, 3)));
    // "[123, 456, 789]"

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitN(s, 5)));  
    // "[12, 34, 56, 78, 9]"

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitN(s, 10))); 
    // "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ]"
```

Note that this favors the earlier parts to hold the extra characters, and it also works when the number of parts is more than the number of characters.

---

#### Appendix

In the above code:

- `?:` is the conditional operator, aka the ternary operator.
- `/` performs integer division. `1 / 2 == 0`.
- `%` performs integer remainder operation. `3 % 2 == 1`. Also, `-1 % 2 == -1`.

#### References

- [JLS 15.25 Conditional Operator ?:](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25)
- [JLS 15.17.2 Division Operator /](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.17.2)
- [JLS 15.17.3 Remainder Operator %](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.17.3)

#### Related questions

- [How does the ternary operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463155/how-does-the-ternary-operator-work)
- [Why does (360 / 24) / 60 = 0 … in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475652/why-does-360-24-60-0-in-java/2475676#2475676)

Comment: +1 for going above and beyond by including N-splits and reference links. Great answer!

Answer (score 8):

You really don't need a regex for this.  Just use `substring()`.

```
int midpoint = str.length() / 2;
String firstHalf = str.substring(0, midpoint);
String secondHalf = str.substring(midpoint);
```

Comment: +1, for a short, simple, concise answer. Let the OP respond and clarify the question if a more complex solution is required.