# Floating point in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does (360 / 24) / 60 = 0 … in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475652/why-does-360-24-60-0-in-java)

Having problems with floats and longs in Java

```
float f = 0.100f;
f = 3/180;
```

At the minute i am trying to do something like this with object and their attributes, but even to this simplest form my program returns 0.0.

I have tried this with Longs as well as still the same result. It's been a long day and maybe it's something simple but I'm at a brick wall.

Comment: You should use `f = 3f/180` instead

Comment: you should look here to know more about type conversion in java(little lengthy but very informative): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: This comes up every week

Answer (score 7):

Your expression `3/180` is performing an integer division, and it is then casting that into the float `f`. In integer division, `3/180` will return `0`, and this is what you are seeing.

What you probably want to do is just add a decimal point to your numbers: `f = 3.0/180.0;`

Comment: Thank you all, as I said incredibly long day and my head is very very sore from banging it on the table. Again thanks to all that helped

Answer (score 3):

`3/180` is **integer** division.
Therefore, the result is truncated to an integer.

You need to perform floating-point division: `3/180f`

Answer (score 3):

You do an integer division. So you get an int which is casted back to a float. Try this:

```
f = 3/180.0;
```

or

```
f = 3/180f;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `3.0/180`. Otherwise, you are dividing two integers and you run into integer truncation. When you do integer division the result is also an integer, not a floating point number.

Comment: Please correct me but I think this is wrong. The second parameter is an int so you do an int division.

Comment: Java will automatically convert that second parameter to a floating point for the calculation because the first parameter is a float. For the computation to work, Java will do that for. You don't have to explicitly make both parameters floats, just one of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I really expected that this would fail.